# Оценка сложности функции

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сложность

Мне необходимо оценить сложность данной функции(код ниже), т.к. сложность `vector::erase` - O(n), то я получаю в худшем случае O(n<sup>3</sup>), где n - это `implicants.size()`.
Правильна ли полученная оценка?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < implicants.size() - 1; ++i)
    for (size_t j = implicants.size() - 1; j > i; --j)
        if (implicants[j].bits == implicants[i].bits)
                implicants.erase(implicants.begin() + j);
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чем?

Comment: @pavel виноват, вопрос, правильно ли я оценил, только начинаю разбираться в этой теме

Comment: Да вроде бы правильно... два цикла дают n^2, + удаление n... Но я что-то никак не соображу, нет ли тут некорректности - после удаления будет меняться размер вектора, не получится ли нарваться на какие-то неприятности. Вроде бы нет, но вот что-то неспокойно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что да, вы оценили верно...

Но если вам не критично расположение элементов в векторе, я бы предложил отсортировать его по полю `bits`, вызвать `unique` с соответствующим предикатом, а потом - `erase`. Самая высокая сложность - у сортировки, так вы получите `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: И даже если расположение элементов важно, можно добиться n log n если завести вектор пар(2 элемент пары это индекс), сначала отсортировать, потом вызвать unique, потом опять отсортировать, но уже по второму элементу пары(лучше наверно даже специальную структуру ввести для этого).